# iPhone will not connect to iTunes after being disabled

Tags: itunes, iphone

I have a iPhone and it got disabled and told me to connect it to ITunes and when I did it would not connect. How to i fix my phone when it's not working.

Comment: what do you mean by disabled ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Possibly http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1212

Comment: If you enter the wrong passcode six or more times, you'll see a message that says iPone disabled. ???

Answer (score 2):

Check the cable and the connector. Perhaps even try with a different computer.

Your iPhone might be damaged, so that it can't work. You didn't say exactly how it got "disabled"?